# Using ALB Deployed via HELM in Terraform Resources

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a requirement to deploy the application via helm/terraform which creates ALB via ingress controller. This ALB is then required for the VPC Link creation between API Gateway and our application. All of this needs to be done in a single terraform apply command.

What I have currently done is following

1. Create EKS Cluster
2. Deploy Application + ingress via helm to create ALB
3. Read ALB via terraform data resource
4. Use the ALB from step 2 to create VPC link

The problem with this approach is everytime we change something in the application e.g version terraform forces the VPC link resources to be redeployed due to change in parent module (application)

I have tried by creating the ALB externally and setting following in tags with ALB Chart 1.4.5/2.4.4

```
ingress.k8s.aws/resource --> LoadBalancer
ingress.k8s.aws/stack --> exisitingalb
elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster --> name of your cluster
```

and following in the ingress

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: "exisitingalb"
```

But this still resulted in the creation of new ALB

Is there a way we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake in my config, i created ALB in different VPC than my EKS cluster. With the following config in the same VPC it worked

```
ingress.k8s.aws/resource --> LoadBalancer
ingress.k8s.aws/stack --> exisitingalb
elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster --> name of your cluster
```

and following in the ingress

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: "exisitingalb"
```